# Dropdown menu item links not working in rails and bootstrap4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bootstrap-4

I have a navbar with a couple dropdowns. The toggle works fine, the navbar collapses at smaller screens, everything works except the links in the dropdowns. Can anyone see what's wrong with this? Also, any of the extra classes I have are just for coloration. I have not included the css here because I think it is irrelevant to the issue.

```
<!-- header -->
<header>
  <!-- navbar -->
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md fixed-top nav-menu navbar-top-image">
    <%= link_to root_path do %>
            <%= image_tag 'yarnn-text-logo.png', width: 120, alt: 'Yarnn icon', id: "logo" %>
        <% end %>
    <button class="navbar-toggler bg-dark" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon mt-2">   
        <i class="fa fa-navicon text-danger"></i>
    </span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-end text-uppercase scrollable" id="myNavbar">
      <ul class="navbar-nav">
          <% if user_signed_in? %>
              <li class="nav-item dropdown" data-toggle="dropdown" data-target="#dashboard_drop"><a class="nav-link text-light m-2 dropdown-toggle" href="#">
                <i class="fas fa-cog text-light mr-2"></i><%= current_user.username %></a>
              <div class="dropdown-menu p-2" id="dashboard_drop">
                <%= link_to "Dashboard", dashboard_path, :class => "dropdown-item navdrop-link" %>
                <%= link_to "Profile", user_path(current_user), :class => "dropdown-item navdrop-link" %>
                <%= link_to "Edit Account", edit_registration_path(current_user), :class => "dropdown-item navdrop-link" %>
                <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                    <%= link_to "My Station", station_path(current_user), :class => "dropdown-item navdrop-link" %>
                    <%= link_to "My Downloads", purchases_path, :class => "dropdown-item navdrop-link" %>
                    <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                    <%= link_to "Upload Track", new_track_path, :class => "dropdown-item navdrop-link" %>
                <%= link_to "Create Album", new_album_path, :class => "dropdown-item navdrop-link" %>
                <%= link_to "Create Blog Post", new_blog_path, :class => "dropdown-item navdrop-link" %>
                <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                <!--- Seller Stuff --->
                <% if current_user.uid? %>
                    <%= link_to "Sell Something", new_listing_path, :class => "dropdown-item navdrop-link" %>
                    <%= link_to "Sales", sales_path, :class => "dropdown-item navdrop-link" %>
                    <%= link_to "Payout", payout_method_path, :class => "dropdown-item navdrop-link" %>
                <% else %>
                    <%= link_to "Become a Seller", payout_method_path, :class => "dropdown-item navdrop-link" %>
                <% end %>
                <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                    <%= link_to  destroy_user_session_path, method: :delete, :class => "dropdown-item navdrop-link current" do %>
                    <i class="fas fa-sign-out-alt text-dark fa-lg"></i> Log Out
              <% end %>
              </div>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <%= link_to notifications_path(current_user), :class => "nav-link text-light m-2" do %>
                    <i class="fas fa-comments text-light mr-1"></i>
                    <% if @notifications.count > 0 %>
                        <span class="site-blue"><%= @notifications.count %></span>
                    <% end %>
                <% end %>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item dropdown" data-toggle="dropdown" data-target="#nav_explore"><a class="nav-link text-light m-2 dropdown-toggle" href="#">
                <i class="fas fa-map-signs text-light"></i> Explore</a>
                <div class="dropdown-menu p-2" id="nav_explore">
                    <%= link_to "Albums", albums_path, :class => "dropdown-item navdrop-link" %>
                  <%= link_to "Tracks", tracks_path, :class => "dropdown-item navdrop-link" %>
                  <%= link_to "Genres", genres_path, :class => "dropdown-item navdrop-link" %>
                  <%= link_to "Blog Posts", blogs_path, :class => "dropdown-item navdrop-link" %>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <%= link_to listings_path, :class => "nav-link text-light m-2 menu-item" do %>
                    <i class="fas fa-shopping-cart text-light"></i> Marketplace
                <% end %>
            </li>
            <%= link_to  destroy_user_session_path, method: :delete, :class => "nav-link text-light m-2 menu-item" do %>
                <i class="fas fa-sign-out-alt site-red fa-lg"></i>
            <% end %>
          <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
  <!-- end of navbar -->
</header>
<!-- end of header -->
```

Comment: So just to be clear, you can see the links, but they do not redirect when clicked? Also, is it every link or just one/some? Also, is this hosted anywhere we can look.  I am thinking some html/css issue with the links being covered up by an element, but without being able to inspect it it is impossible to say really.

Comment: Yeah, everything appears as expected, but none of the dropdown menu item links go anywhere. I wish this was live, but I am in the process of restyling the entire site with Bootstrap so I do not have that option for you. All the links change to the pointer cursor when you hover them and you can see the url they are supposed to link to showing in the far bottom left. I'll try to inspect it and see what I can find.

Comment: Another thing, it allows you to right click the link and open a new window or tab. You just can't click it.

Comment: Is there possibly some javascript that is cancelling out the default action for some reason?  Something that marks `a` clicks with `preventDefault()` or something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this to work, but I had to rebuild the functionality completely, this time using buttons from the Bootstrap documentation. I figure the functionality is the important part, I can style it to my liking later. This is also my full navbar, I left some extraneous elements out earlier to make it less dense.

```
<!-- header -->
<header>
  <!-- navbar -->
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md fixed-top nav-menu navbar-top-image">
    <%= link_to root_path do %>
            <%= image_tag 'yarnn-text-logo.png', width: 120, alt: 'Yarnn icon', id: "logo" %>
        <% end %>
    <button class="navbar-toggler bg-dark" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon mt-2">   
               <i class="fa fa-navicon text-danger"></i>
            </span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-end text-uppercase scrollable" id="myNavbar">
      <ul class="navbar-nav">
        <% unless user_signed_in? %>

          <div class="dropdown">
                      <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle m-2" type="button" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">
                        EXPLORE
                        <span class="caret"></span>
                      </button>
                      <ul class="dropdown-menu p-2" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
                        <li class="dropdown-item navdrop-link"><%= link_to "Albums", albums_path %></li>
                        <li class="dropdown-item navdrop-link"><%= link_to "Tracks", tracks_path %></li>
              <li class="dropdown-item navdrop-link"><%= link_to "Genres", genres_path %></li>
              <li class="dropdown-item navdrop-link"><%= link_to "Blog Posts", blogs_path %></li>
                      </ul>
                    </div>

            <li class="nav-item">
                <%= link_to listings_path, :class => "nav-link text-light m-2 menu-item" do %>
                          <i class="fas fa-shopping-cart text-light"></i> Marketplace
                        <% end %>
            </li>

            <li class="nav-item">
              <%= link_to "Login", new_user_session_path, :class => "nav-link text-light m-2 menu-item" %>
            </li>

            <li class="nav-item">
              <%= link_to "Register", new_user_registration_path, :class => "nav-link text-light m-2 menu-item" %>
            </li>
          <% else %>

              <div class="dropdown">
                          <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle m-2" type="button" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">
                            <i class="fas fa-cog text-light mr-2"></i><%= current_user.username %>
                            <span class="caret"></span>
                          </button>
                          <ul class="dropdown-menu p-2" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
                            <li class="dropdown-item navdrop-link"><%= link_to "Dashboard", dashboard_path %></li>
                            <li class="dropdown-item navdrop-link"><%= link_to "Profile", user_path(current_user) %></li>
                  <li class="dropdown-item navdrop-link"><%= link_to "Edit Account", edit_registration_path(current_user) %></li>
                  <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                  <li class="dropdown-item navdrop-link"><%= link_to "My Station", station_path(current_user) %></li>
                  <li class="dropdown-item navdrop-link"><%= link_to "My Downloads", purchases_path %></li>
                  <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                  <li class="dropdown-item navdrop-link"><%= link_to "Upload Track", new_track_path %></li>
                            <li class="dropdown-item navdrop-link"><%= link_to "Create Album", new_album_path %></li>
                  <li class="dropdown-item navdrop-link"><%= link_to "Create Blog Post", new_blog_path %></li>
                  <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>

                    <!--- Seller Stuff --->
                                <% if current_user.uid? %>
                                <li class="dropdown-item navdrop-link"><%= link_to "Sell Something", new_listing_path %></li>
                            <li class="dropdown-item navdrop-link"><%= link_to "Sales", sales_path %></li>
                  <li class="dropdown-item navdrop-link"><%= link_to "Payout", payout_method_path %></li>
                    <% else %>
                    <li class="dropdown-item navdrop-link"><%= link_to "Become a Seller", payout_method_path %></li>
                    <% end %>

                    <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                    <li class="dropdown-item navdrop-link current"><%= link_to destroy_user_session_path, method: :delete do %>
                            <i class="fas fa-sign-out-alt text-dark fa-lg"></i> Log Out
                      <% end %></li>
                          </ul>
                        </div>

            <li class="nav-item">
                <%= link_to notifications_path(current_user), :class => "nav-link text-light m-2" do %>
                            <i class="fas fa-comments text-light mr-1"></i>
                            <% if @notifications.count > 0 %>
                                <span class="site-blue"><%= @notifications.count %></span>
                            <% end %>
                        <% end %>
                    </li>

                    <div class="dropdown">
                      <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle m-2" type="button" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">
                        EXPLORE
                        <span class="caret"></span>
                      </button>
                      <ul class="dropdown-menu p-2" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
                        <li class="dropdown-item navdrop-link"><%= link_to "Albums", albums_path %></li>
                        <li class="dropdown-item navdrop-link"><%= link_to "Tracks", tracks_path %></li>
              <li class="dropdown-item navdrop-link"><%= link_to "Genres", genres_path %></li>
              <li class="dropdown-item navdrop-link"><%= link_to "Blog Posts", blogs_path %></li>
                      </ul>
                    </div>

            <li class="nav-item">
                <%= link_to listings_path, :class => "nav-link text-light m-2 menu-item" do %>
                          <i class="fas fa-shopping-cart text-light"></i> Marketplace
                        <% end %>
            </li>

            <%= link_to  destroy_user_session_path, method: :delete, :class => "nav-link text-light m-2 menu-item" do %>
                <i class="fas fa-sign-out-alt site-red fa-lg"></i>
          <% end %>

          <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
  <!-- end of navbar -->
</header>
<!-- end of header -->
```